# make a login button with yoroi on a webpage

Tags: blockchain, cardano

how can I create a functional "log in with yoroi" button? as if it were with metamask. I was looking in the documentation of Yoroi, and Cardano, but I couldn't find how to do it or at least the language that I have to use, I would appreciate your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option available with Yoroi for now. But you can do that with Nami wallet.